# expectation of the last arrival time of a poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

Consider a Poisson process with rate $λ$ and let $L$ be the time of the last arrival in the
interval $[0, t]$, with $L = 0$ if there was no arrival. (a) Compute $E(t − L)$. (b) What happens when we let $t → ∞$ in the answer to (a)?

When I compute 
$E(t − L)$,
I condition on $N(L)$.
$$E(t − L)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E(t-L\mid N(L)=n)P(N(L)=n)$$

By definition of $L$, $N(L)=N(t)$,
$$E(t − L)=tP(N(t)=0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(t-L\mid N(t)=n)P(N(t)=n)$$

For $N(t)=n$, $L=T_n$ where $T_n$ is $Gamma(n, λ)$ distributed, 
$$E(t − L)=t\exp(-\lambda t)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E(t-T_n)P(N(t)=n)\\=t\exp(-\lambda t)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(t-n/\lambda)\exp(-\lambda t)\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}\\=t\exp(-\lambda t)+t\exp(-\lambda t)(\exp(\lambda t)-1)-t\exp(-\lambda t)\exp(\lambda t)=0$$

What's wrong?
The answer is $(1/λ)(1 − \exp
(−λt))$
How can I attained this answer?

Comment: Your claim that $E(t-L \mid N(t)=n) = E(t - T_n)$ cannot be correct, since the left side is always positive and the right side can be negative for large enough $n$.

Comment: Oh, it should be $E(t−L∣N(t)=n)=E(t−T_n∣N(t)=n)$ but it seem difficult to compute $E(t−T_n∣N(t)=n)$?

Comment: Suggestion: $\{N(t) = n\} = \{T_n \le t, T_{n+1} > t\}$.

Comment: How can this equality help me to compute$E(t−Tn∣N(t)=n)$

Comment: I'd look for a symmetry argument showing that $t-L$ has the same distribution as the first arrival time.  (There's also the question of what to do if there are no arrivals in $[0,t]$.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Once you condition on event $N(t)=n$, you know that in the interval $[0,t]$ there are $n$ arrivals with all inter-arrival times distributed identically. The expected value of each of these $n+1$ inter-arrival times is therefore simply $\frac{t}{n+1}$. Note also that this value applies to the case $n=0$, since $\frac{t}{n+1}=t$ then. Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(t-L) &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{E(t-L\mid N(t)=n)P(N(t)=n)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{t}{n+1}\dfrac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(\lambda t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}e^{-\lambda t}} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\left[\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}}\right) - e^{-\lambda t}\right] \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\lambda}\left(1 - e^{-\lambda t}\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Now as $t\to \infty,\;$ clearly, $\;E(t-L)\to \dfrac{1}{\lambda}$. This is the mean inter-arrival waiting time for the process, and this makes sense: as $t\to\infty$, the chance of getting no arrivals approaches $0$ and $t-L$ approaches an inter-arrival waiting time.